# STM32 12v relay driver circuit

Tags: transistors, diodes, relay, stm32

I spent the day looking for a circuit driver to control a 12V Omron [G4A](https://omronfs.omron.com/en_US/ecb/products/pdf/en-g4a.pdf)  (rated current 75mA@12v) relay with 3.3v GPIO of STM32, without success. According to my calculations the circuit below should work, is it? if not can you give me the R1 value, and the reference of the diode and the transistor please?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqpwdg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You want to saturate the transistor, lower your base resistor to a few hundred ohms.

Comment: Why did you connect the GPIO to the ground via R2? R2<R1 so most of the current is going through this route, not the gate. Maybe that's why the transistor is not turning ON.

Comment: @varun, I need a led to check relay. If i put it below the diode , the result is same not? where i can put it?

Comment: Try putting the LED (D2) and R2 between Emitter and gnd. The problem with this is, LED should be able to handle the current in that loop. Here the coil resistance is 160 and R2 is 1k. Total of 1.160K which gives 13mA of current for 15V. If the LED can handle 13mA you are good. Else increase R2.

Comment: For this you better use a N-Channel MOSFET with a Vth about 2V, you'll not need to care about R1 and will have less heat dissipation.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking for much simpler single component solution - relay driver chip. For example we've been using [NUD3160](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nud3160-d.pdf) with Omron G5V for years without any problems.

You may notice that its internal schematics is pretty close to what you were trying to do with BJT.

Answer (score 0):

how much current will transistor pull?

Ic =approx= (gain) x (current in 22k)
= (100 min) x ((3.3V-0.6V)/22000R)
= 100 x 2.7V/22000R
= 12mA min

Is this enough to close your relay? Maybe not.

Note also that the assumption that the pin actually produces 3.3V at the output could be lower.

Comment: So, lower R1 down to a value obtained reversing the above formula...